# How can I join two Tableau worksheets based on row name

Tags: python, join, merge, tableau-api

In Tableau, how can I join two worksheet results by row name?

original dataset:

```
   ad_storeid     num_ads   sales_storeid   num_sales
----------------------------------------------------------------
       1            20             1             50
       1            30             2             70
       3            20           null           null
      null         null            4             80
```

**df1:** sum num_ads by ad_storeid:

```
ad_storeid      num_ads
    1              50
    3              20
```

**df2:** sum num_sales by sales_storeid:

```
sales_storeid   num_sales
    1               50
    2               70
    4               80
```

Suppose I got df1 in worksheet1 and df2 in worksheet2, how can I merge the two tables in Tableau?

Expected result:

```
store_id   num_ads   num_sales
   1         50         50
   2        null        70
   3         20        null
   4        null        80
```

I know how to do that in Python, but how can I do that in Tableau? I can't use a unified 'storeid' in one worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of linking two worksheets you can perform same in single worksheet. Try below approach:

Create a calculation `store_ID` and write below code and place on rows:

```
IF ZN(INT([Ad Storeid])) = ZN(INT([Sales Storeid]))
THEN [Ad Storeid]
ELSEIF ZN(INT([Ad Storeid])) < ZN(INT([Sales Storeid])) 
THEN [Sales Storeid]
ELSEIF ZN(INT([Ad Storeid])) > ZN(INT([Sales Storeid]))
THEN [Ad Storeid]
END
```

Now for num_ads create one more calculation `num_ads`  and write below code:

```
IF ZN(INT([Ad Storeid])) = ZN(INT([Store_ID]))
THEN { FIXED [Ad Storeid] : SUM([Num Ads])}
ELSE
NULL
END
```

For num_sales create one more calculation `num_sales` and write below code:

```
IF ZN(INT([Store_ID])) = ZN(INT([Store_ID]))
THEN [Num Sales]
ELSE
NULL
END
```

[image]